# Azure IOT Hub, is it possible to have multiple devices that uses the same authentication credentials?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I was successfully connect to Azure Iot Hub using both X.509 CA method and shared keys.

For using certificates, it's clear, each device shall have unique cert/keys inside, signed by Root CA. This is huge effort and a waste of small embedded MCU resources to store those certificates anyhow.

Now I tried SAS with tokens according this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-sas?tabs=node#authenticating-a-device-to-iot-hub

For a device, I generate the token in Azure portal

```
HostName=xxxxxx.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=mydevice1;SharedAccessSignature=SharedAccessSignature sr=xxxxxx.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fmydevice1&sig=ufWZ4OVyJpWu4EbyRESbAzY7kfTahcgT7n5P0xA4WU0%3D&se=4833693930
```

This token is also unique, the has contains the name of the device within. My embedded device connects just fine with this method too, but we are in the design process of potentially have tons of devices.

Is there any way to connect to Iot Hub with multiple devices, using the same token, in order the firmware to be the same? Or any other method to authenticate.

Thanks for any hints,

**EDIT for Roman's hint**

I already tried to have 2 devices with the same keys which is possible.
But the problem is that generated token (used to actually connect) is different, due to the fact that token includes device name.

All I want is a unique token across all devices (that can be differentiated by their name). Is it possible to use other login string than (generated, encrypted) token?

**Personal note**

I can't imagine how Microsoft thought about having thousands of devices with unique firmware inside, each one. Say home appliances. This is a huge effort and cost at manufacturing stage. Never mention certificate costs if involved or 3'rd party token services?

Comment: When you connect the second device with the same device ID, IoT Hub disconnects the first one. So every device needs its own device ID. For the rest, Dominic's answer is excellent.

Comment: another way (for development purposes) your devices can be created/registered in the IoT Hub with the same *symmetric key*, which it will simplify a device connection string.

Comment: Roman, can you elaborate this? See my edited post

Answer (score 1):

Each device needs a unique ID and security token. If you're connecting directly to an IoT hub, the only options are X.509 or SAS.

An alternative is to use DPS (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-dps/) - this approach has the device connect first to DPS to obtain the connection information it needs to connect to an IoT hub. The device still needs unique credentials to authenticate with DPS, but in addition to X.509 and SAS, the device can use information stored in its TPM. I don't know if your devices have a TPM, and what options you have for storing credentials in the TPM.

Another option to consider is using a token service. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-sas?tabs=node#create-a-token-service-to-integrate-existing-devices

Answer (score 0):

Based on your testing requirements such as using the one common SAS Token for any device registered to your Azure IoT Hub:

1. From the portal, copy a connection string from a *device* Shared access policy.

example:

```
HostName=####.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=device;SharedAccessKey=####
```

2. Create a SAS Token from this connection string.

example:

```
SharedAccessSignature sr=####.azure-devices.net&sig=####&se=1711710236&skn=device
```

3. Use this SAS Token for any device registered in your Azure Iot Hub.

For quick test, you can use a *MQTTBox Client*, where the Password = SAS Token

[image]

[image]

For more testing, just change the highlighted deviceId (in my test the deviceId = *abc-001*)

Note, that in this case (for test purposes), each device needs to know its DeviceId and this common SAS Token.

Comment: Unfortunately this not works, SAS tokens contains DeviceID so will be unique.

Comment: I just updated my answer from my testing. Note, that the SAS Token doesn't contain a deviceId and it is valid for any registered device in the IoT Hub.

Comment: hmmm... but I tested with device. you gave me work! :))) let you know if this is working...

Comment: have a look at the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-sas?tabs=node#use-a-shared-access-policy-to-access-on-behalf-of-a-device